# Call a function of one of a list of children components of the parent component using reference

Tags: reactjs

For my website I want to include a feature that helps users randomly click a link programatically. The event happens in the parent component called StreamingPlaza, and its has a list of children components called StreamingCard, each containing a streaming link. Below is my code:

**StreamingPlaza**

```
class StreamingPlaza extends Component {

  state = {
    ......
    }

  roomclicks = [];

  componentDidMount() {

    //Approach 1//
    this.roomclicks[0].current.handleClick();

    //Approach 2//
    this.roomclicks[0].props.click = true;
    ......
  }

  setRef = (ref) => {
    this.roomclicks.push(ref);
  }

  renderRoom = (room) => {

    return <StreamingCard info={room} ref={this.setRef} click={false}></StreamingCard>;

  }


  render () {

    const rooms = this.props.rooms;

    return (
        { rooms && rooms.map (room => {
            return this.renderRoom(room);  
        })
      }
    );
  }
```

**StreamingCard**

```
class StreamingCard extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ......
    }
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    document.getElementById("link").click();
  }

  render() {
    return (
       ✔️ Streaming Link: <a id="link" href=......></a>
    );
}
```

Regarding Approach 1, the console reported the error **Cannot read property handClick of undefined**. After I removed "current", it said that **this.roomclicks[0].handleClick is not a function**. Regarding Approach 2, I was not able to modify the props in this way, as the console reported that "click" is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1 is basically how its need to be done, **but with React API**.

See [`React.createRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactcreateref)

```
class StreamingPlaza extends Component {
  roomclicks = React.createRef([]);

  componentDidMount() {
    // 0 is room.id
    this.roomclicks.current[0].handleClick();
  }

  renderRoom = (room) => {
    return (
      <StreamingCard
        info={room}
        ref={(ref) => (this.roomclicks.current[room.id] = ref)}
        click={false}
      ></StreamingCard>
    );
  };

  render() {
    const rooms = this.props.rooms;
    return rooms.map((room) => {
      return this.renderRoom(room);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I replaced room.id with 0 and got the TypeError "Cannot set property '0' of null."

Comment: I just fixed the issue by assigning the "roomclicks" ref to an element. However, it still reported that "this.roomclicks.current[0].handleClick is not a function." I checked that this.roomclicks.current[0] is indeed the child component expected.

Comment: No one can guess how your app is structured, thats a generic answer